# How to load json files with rasdaman

Tags: python, geospatial, raster

im studying Array database management systems a bit, in particular [Rasdaman](https://doc.rasdaman.org/index.html), i understand superficially the architecture and how the system works with sets and multidimensional arrays instead of tables as it is usual in relational dbms, im trying to save my own type of data to check if this type of databases can give me better performance to my specific problem(geospatial data in a particular format: [DGGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_global_grid)), to do so i have created my own basic type based on a structure as indicated by the documentation, created my array type, set type and finally my collection for testing, i'm trying to insert data into this collection with the following idea:

```
query_executor.execute_update_from_file("insert into test_json_dict values decode($1, 'json', '{\"formatParameters\": {\"domain\": \"[0:1000]\",\"basetype\": struct { char k, long v } } })'", "...path.../rasdapy-demo/dggs_sample.json")
```

I'm using the library [rasdapy](https://tutorial.rasdaman.org/rasdapy-tutorial/) to work from python instead of using rasql only(i use it anyways to validate small things), but i have been fighting with error messages that give little to no information:

```
Internal error: RasnetClientComm::executeQuery(): illegal status value 5
```

My source file has this type of data into it:

```
{
  "N1": 6
}
```

A simple dict with a key and a value, i wanna save both things, i also tried to have a bigger dict with multiples keys and values on it but as the rasdaman decode function expects a basetype definition if i understand correctly i tried to change my data source format as a simple dict. It is obvious to see that i'm not doing the appropriate definition for decoding or that my source file has the wrong format but i haven't been able to find any examples on the web, any ideas on how to proceed? maybe i am even doing this whole thing from the wrong perspective and maybe i should try to use the OGC Web Coverage Service (WCS) standard ? i don't understand this yet so i have been avoiding it, anyways any advice or direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I have been trying to load CSV data with the following format:

```
1 930
2 461
..
```

and the following query

```
query_executor.execute_update_from_file("insert into test_json_dict values decode($1, 'csv', '{\"formatParameters\": {\"domain\": \"[1:255]\",\"basetype\": struct { char key, long value } } })'", "...path.../rasdapy-demo/dggs_sample_4.csv")
```

but still no results, even tho it looks quite similar to the documentation example in [Look for the CSV/JSON examples](https://doc.rasdaman.org/04_ql-guide.html#id28) but no results still. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my problem was trying to use the rasdapy library, this lib works fine but when working with data formats like csv and json it is best to use the rasql command line option, it states in the documentation :

> filePaths - An array of absolute paths to input files to be decoded, e.g. ["/path/to/rgb.tif"]. This improves ingestion performance if the data is on the same machine as the rasdaman server, as the network transport is bypassed and the data is read directly from disk. Supported only for GDAL, NetCDF, and GRIB data formats.

and also it says:

> As a first parameter the data to be decoded must be specified. Technically this data must be in the form of a 1D char array. Usually it is specified as a query input parameter with $1, while the binary data is attached with the --file option of the rasql command-line client tool, or with the corresponding methods in the client API.

It would be interesting to note if rasdapy takes this into account. Anyhow use of rasql gives way better response errors so i recommend that to anyone having a similar problem.

An example command could be:

```
rasql -q 'insert into test_basic values decode($1, "csv", "{ \"formatParameters\": {\"domain\": \"[0:1,0:2]\",\"basetype\": \"long\" } }")' --out string --file "/home/rasdaman/Documents/TFM/include/DGGS-Comparison/rasdapy-demo/dggs_sample_6.csv" --user rasadmin --passwd rasadmin
```

using this data:

```
1,2,3,2,1,3
```

After that you just got to start making it more and more complex as you need.